# Нужен ли дефис после приставки "псевдо-"?

Tags: орфография, приставка

Команда университета Уотерлу (Онтарио, Канада) опубликовала результаты исследования, посвященного способности распознавать псевдоглубокомысленные высказывания.

Comment: Дополнение. Еще "псевдо" пишется через дефис с аббревиатурами: псевдо-ЭВМ, псевдо-СМИ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: **псевдоглубокомысленные высказывания.**

**ПСЕВДО**... [от греч. pséudos - ложь, вымысел] Первая часть сложных слов. Вносит зн. сл.: ложный, мнимый. Псевдогерой, псевдогуманист, псевдоделовой, псевдоинтерес, псевдоклассицизм, псевдонародный, псевдонаука, псевдопатриотизм, псевдосоциалистический.

**Розенталь:** [§ 38. Сложные существительные](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=48#pp48)

**В словаре Лопатина** "Слитно, раздельно или через дефис" (2012) также указывается слитное написание форманта ПСЕВДО.

Дефисное написание псевдо- в двух случаях:  перед прописной буквой и дефисно пишущимся словом.

Псевдо-Дионисий, с именем которого связано апофатическое богословие, работал почти в то же время, хотя и в другом месте. [С. С. Неретина(2006)]